# Perl ifelse and else-block not working

Tags: regex, perl

I am learning to code in Perl and I am writing a conjugator for Dutch adjectives. My ifelse and else block won't execute. I am totally new to programming and I don't see why this happens. Running the code does not give a syntax error; but it does not de to regex substituions in the else-block.

```
$woord=shift(@ARGV);    #read input word from cmd-line
$evorm=$woord;
$svorm=$woord;
$comp=$woord;
$compmete=$woord;
$compmets=$woord;
$super=$woord;
$supermete=$woord;

# vorm met -e #

if($evorm=~/ig\b/){
    $evorm=~s/(.*)/\1e/;    # add -e wordstem
    print "vorm met buigings-e: $evorm\n";      
}
elsif($evorm=~/@n\b/){                                              
    print "vorm met buigings-e: $evorm\n";  # print evorm ending in -@n (without adding final -e)
    }
else{   #these are subsitutions for conjugation (regex is correct)
$evorm=~s/([^(oo)(ee)(aa)(uu)(ie)(eu)][aeiou])([bdfklnmprst])\b/\1\2\2/;# verdubbeling consonant voor volle klinker: dom > domme, fel > felle, gek > gekke, plat > platte
$evorm=~s/((aa)|(ee)|(oo)|(ie)|(eu)|(oe)|(ui))f\b/\1v/; # stemhebbend maken van -f-: lief > liev: 
$evorm=~s/((aa)|(ee)|(oo)|(ie)|(eu)|(oe)|(ui))s\b/\1z/; # stemmehebbend maken van -s-: dwaas > dwaaz
$evorm=~s/([aeou])\1([bdfgklmnrstvz])\b/\1\2/;  # dubbele klinker enkelvoudig maken voor medeklinkers: groot > grot, braav > brav
$evorm=~s/(.*)/\1e/;        # voegt -e toe aan de (al dan niet voorbewerkte) stam
print "vorm met buigings-e: $evorm\n";  # print evorm
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "won't execute"? Does it follow the wrong branch? Produce an error?

Comment: Perhaps you should change some of you comments to English. I can see you are into linguistics, but most of us dont.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the if/elsif/else statements, but `$evorm=~s/(.*)/\1e/;` can be more simply written as `$evorm .= 'e';`.

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying. It does not give an error; but it follows the if branch even if the input string does not contain word final "ig"

Comment: enable warnings!  and strict

Comment: If you'd enable warnings or strict, you'd have a warning/error about @n. You want to write `$evorm=~/\@n\b/`

Comment: `[^(oo)(ee)(aa)(uu)(ie)(eu)]` does not do what you seem to think it does. Inside a character class bracket all characters are literal (except `[, ] and -`), so that part of your regex does the same as `[^(o)eaui]`, and note that without a quantifier (`*`, `+` etc), it will only match one character, for example `X` or `p`. If you want to negate those matches, use a negative lookaaround assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable strict and warnings for all code; they are there to help you.  (You will need to actually declare all your variables, then.)   Run the following snippet and it will give you a clue:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $evorm = '';
if ($evorm =~ /ig\b/) {
}
elsif ($evorm =~ /@n\b/) {
}
```

Comment: I enabled strict, did as suggested and now it works.

My mistake was in the regex syntax the backreferences should be done by $1 not \1

Comment: @GJacobs, Well, that's an issue, but it's not your problem. Your problem is that you did `/@n\b/` instead of `/\@n\b/`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your if structure doesn't work because you don't check anything. You just replace or remove something in a string..

Try this : save the string in a local variable and then match it like this :

```
 my $test1  = $evorm;
 $test1 =~/ig\b/;

 my $test2 = $evorm;
 $test2 =~/@n\b/;

if($evorm eq $test1 ){
$evorm=~s/(.*)/\1e/;    # voegt -e toe aan de (al dan niet voorbewerkte) stam
print "vorm met buigings-e: $evorm\n";      
}
elsif($evorm eq $test2){                                              
   print "vorm met buigings-e: $evorm\n";  # druk evorm af die eindigt op -@n zonder -e toe te voegen
  }
else{
.....
```

Try this, so now you actually check on something ;)
Don't know if that's what you want? Just a wild guess

Comment: This yields the same results. Every input string is run through the if-block even the once not containing "ig\b". Whatever the input it ignores ifelse and else completely.